# Reading files with multiple delimiters in c++

Tags: c++, delimiter, getline

I have a text file to read, but it is not formatted pretty (on purpose).

I have to sort the data into a struct, and the data types are different so first I'm sorting them into an array so I can sort them into the struct based on order.
I made a code to get a line, then test if there are spaces in it, if there is a space, it scans it again using ' ' as a delimiter. If not, it just stores the string into the array.

Here is the code:

```
int nextw(ifstream &file, string array[]){

    string line;
    string token;
    stringstream iss;
    size_t foundspace;

    int i = 0;

    while(getline(file, line)){
            iss << line;

            foundspace = line.find(" ");
            if(foundspace != string::npos){
                    while(getline(iss, token, ' ')){
                            array[i++] = token;
                    }
            }
            else
                    array[i++] = line;
    }
    return i;
}
```

It returns the count of the array.

The problem is it skips a row of data.
For example, I have:

```
data data data data data
data
data
data
data
data
skipped_data skipped_data
data
data
etc...
```

Only that single line of 2 words of data with a space delimiter are being skipped. The line is not being treated as if that line was a single string, it is just not in the array at all.

edit: added more code

Comment: Well, I found out >> does what I was looking for and I was complicating things with getline() for 2 days. I'm actually still not sure why my code above didn't work. I can't answer my own question for a few more hours so it still will show up as unanswered for a little while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured out ">>" works instead of getline().